# Spring MVC- Binding handler method parameter to type selected at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Similar to [Spring MVC abstract class binding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16598571/1503554), I have handler methods with an @ModelAttribute parameter which is an interface. Based on some of the properties of the incoming request, I want to programmatically select an implementation to instantiate and then bind it to the request body using whatever Spring has down in its guts for marshalling into objects.

Is this possible and what Spring components would I need to make use of to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to resolve your custom method parameters. Suppose your interface is `CustomInterface`, then:

```
public class CustomInterfaceResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(CustomInterface.class);
    }


    @Override
    public CustomInterface resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        // instantiate CustomInterface impls based on request parameters
        // and return it of course
    }
}
```

`supportsParameter` method ensures that this resolver only resolves arguemnts of type `CustomInterface` and `resolveArgument` method, does the actual mechanics of resolving the argument.

After implementing this class, add it to your list of current argument resolvers. For example, in java config:

```
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(customArgumentResolver);
    }
    ...
}
```

After that, any time you add a `CustomInterface` to your controller method argument, `CustomInterfaceResolver#resolveArgument` would be called to resolve the argument:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/somewhere")
public class CustomInterfaceController {
    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity doSomething(CustomInterface ci, ...) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already looked at this and it doesn't achieve what I'm hoping to do. It creates instances but doesn't do any binding to the incoming request.

Comment: You have access to the `WebDataBinderFactory `, which can be used for `binding` purposes