# How instantiate a concrete class in init binder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-binding

I have to bind an abstract class to my controller request handler method.

Before I instantiate the concrete class with `@ModelAttribute` annotated method:

```
@ModelAttribute("obj")
public AbstractObh getObj(final HttpServletRequest request){
    return AbstractObj.getInstance(myType);     
}
```

But now I try to do that without the `@ModelAttribute` annotated method, beacause every call to controller trigger model attribute annotated method too.

So I try to get concrete class with **InitBinder** and a **custom editor**, but it doesn't work.

**My Init Binder:**

```
@InitBinder(value="obj")
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(AbstractObj.class, new SchedaEditor());
}
```

And **My Post Handler**:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@Valid @ModelAttribute("obj") AbstractObj obj, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    //my handler
    }
```

This is my **ObjEditor**:

```
@Override
public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try{
        if(text == null){
            setValue(new ConcreteObj());
        }else{
            setValue(objService.findById(Long.valueOf(text)));
        }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        setValue(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ModelAttribute is just a command object. It is not intended to have variuos implementations depending on request parameters.
WebDataBinder just influences how all parameters are being mapped to command fields.
So - create simple command object with field of type AbstractObj .

```
public class CommandObject {

    private AbstractObj type;

    public void setType(AbstractObj type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand very well.. Can you explain "So - create simple command object with String field type and let it return any other objects you want." ?? Or can you post piece of code??

Comment: Just found that you use service in mapping. Made the corresponding changes. The field will be of type AbstractObj (base class). Besides - keep initBinder. Thus field of type AbstractObj will be injected using this custom editor.